# Datatype for time zone variable

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am going to save users data in theirs timezone.

Should I use `varchar`, `datetime` or another datatype for the time field, and why?

I'm working with PHP on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't store date with timezone in database. In db store in UTC (default Laravel configuration) this base date you will convert when some of your user will choose other then default timezone.

User model should have char field "timezone" with value for example: 'Europe/London' or 'Europe/Warsaw' or 'Asia/Vladivostok'. You can find all timezones in [camroncade/timezone package](https://github.com/camroncade/timezone). Next when you display datetime in application you will append user's timezone to Carbon datetime object and convert to proper time.

```
$value // your base UTC datetime
$value = new Carbon($value);   
$value->setTimezone(Auth:user()->timezone);
print $value->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') // datetime in user's timezone
```

Keep in mind that you can automate conversion process using date casting by overriding default asDateTime method in your Model od BaseModel.

```
protected function asDateTime($value)
    {
        if($value instanceof Carbon) {
            return $value;
        } elseif($value instanceof \DateTime) {
            $value = $value->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        }

        $value = new Carbon($value);

        if(Auth::user()) {
            $value->setTimezone(Auth::user()->timezone);
        }

        return $value;
    }
```

This method will be fired every time you will request datetime field defined in Model in *protected $dates* property (created_at, updated_at are in default).

Comment: hi i got an error on $value = new Carbon($value); the error says DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (1474430400) at position 8 (0): Unexpected character @Adiasz

Comment: im using laravel 5.3

Comment: 1474430400 - is the date timestamp so you have to create object that way $value = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(1474430400); If you have dates in multiple formats then you need to check if before create Carbon object. Take a look at docs http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **datetime** and timestamp both. better go for **datetime** data type that's good for retrieving.

Answer (score 0):

Always try to store datetime in milisecond so you can convert that in specific timezone. And you can use varchar and string(in laravel) to store it.